# Bibliography appearing twice in Table of Contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, bibliographies, letterspacing

I have two issues in my Table of Contents.

1. Bibliography appearing twice in Table of Contents
2. Title of Table of Content has improper spacing
   [image: TOC]

Latex below:
1. For Bibliography

```
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{references}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{SVIT} Matek, Tadej and Timej Zebec, Svit. (2016). GitHub open source project recommendation system. 

\bibitem{Yun}
Zhang, Yun and Lo, David and Kochhar, Pavneet Singh and Xia, Xin and Li, Quanlai and Sun, Jianling. (2017). Detecting similar repositories on GitHub. 

\bibitem{Surbhi}
Sharma, Surbhi and Mahajan, Anuj. (2017). A Collaborative Filtering Recommender System for Github. International Journal of Emerging Technologies in Engineering Research (IJETER). 

\end{thebibliography}
```

2. I have used a chapter setting to automatically center all chapters. But for some reason Table of Contents seems spaced out. No other chapter or section has that error.

MWE

```
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}{5pt}{4pt}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{\sethead{}{}{}\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
```

Comment: Just remove `\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} `

Comment: What about Table of Contents Error?

Comment: You may try `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}` after loading `tocloft` package

Answer (score 2):

You mix 2 different ways to produce a bibliography.

Either use

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{references}
```

or

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{SVIT} Matek, Tadej and Timej Zebec, Svit. (2016). GitHub open source project recommendation system. 

\bibitem{Yun}
Zhang, Yun and Lo, David and Kochhar, Pavneet Singh and Xia, Xin and Li, Quanlai and Sun, Jianling. (2017). Detecting similar repositories on GitHub. 

\bibitem{Surbhi}
Sharma, Surbhi and Mahajan, Anuj. (2017). A Collaborative Filtering Recommender System for Github. International Journal of Emerging Technologies in Engineering Research (IJETER). 

\end{thebibliography}
```

but not both (unless you want two bibliographies)